# Making Images not Appear in Android Gallery

Tags: java, android, camera, gallery

I'm working on an app where I will be taking images and displaying them in that app. However I notice that those images show up in their own category of the gallery when the gallery is opened. I'm wondering if it's possible to take photos with the existing camera and keep them hidden from the gallery. Perhaps its something I have to add to the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a `.nomedia` file wherever you store your images and then clear your application's data to delete those images so the gallery doesn't have them cached